# IE9 stops loading page after one minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am loading almost 120 thumbnails in single page (Nothing else i can do). Ultimate loading time in developer tool shows over one minute. In all browser it works fine, but in IE9 when loading time reached one minute it stops loading other stuff.

```
var allImg = $("#container").find("img");

function loadImgs(){
        var total = allImg.length;
        var pretotal = 0;

        allImg.each(function(i,e){

            $(this).load($(this).attr("src"),null, function(){
                    pretotal++;
                    var totalperc = (100 * pretotal) / total;   
                            $(".perccont div").width( totalperc + "%");             
                            if(total == pretotal){$("#preloader").fadeOut();
                        }
            });
        });     
    }
```

This preloader works great till around 20%, after it reaches limit of 1 minute it stops loading.

[image]

Is there anything that i can do?

Comment: I must confess .. I am curious about the reason for this. But: Honestly, I don't understand the concept. It looks to me like you are trying to load images via Ajax. I didn't even know this was possible using .load() ...

Comment: Ok ... I did some researching. Pre-loading images is only meaningful if the images are not yet present and visible in the DOM (otherwise they will be loaded anyway). Then the .load() Ajax method is only meaningful for loading HTML ... at least according to the docs (http://api.jquery.com/load/). Finally the usual way of pre-loading images in jQuery is `$('<img />').load(function() { ... }).attr('src', 'path/to/image.png');`

Comment: Actually these images are already there in HTML page, but i need to create one preloader until all images gets loaded. So i've used this trick. Lemme try your way to load.

Comment: If the images are in the HTML and visible, the images will automatically be loaded on page load. Adding additional Ajax loads will not help then

Comment: @devnull69 , Ultimately i've removed load particular for IE.